# Trying to make a cron job to move my files from desktop to a temp file at the end of the day

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, cron

I want to make a simple cron job that moves all the files on my desktop to a temp folder at the end of the day. for debugging
I wrote this bash script that works when I run it using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mv ~/Desktop/* ~/Temp
```

saved the script and I am using the following cron job:

```
59 23 * * * /bin/mv /Users/username/Desktop/* /Users/username/Temp
```

The cron job executes when I tested printing something to a file. but somehow it will not move files? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It might be the privacy controls on your Desktop folder; see [this Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted). BTW, I'd add the `-n` option to `mv`, to avoid data loss if there's a filename conflict.

Comment: This worked very well! Thank you for your help and I added the -n option as well thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to fix your bash script with correct user context.

Since `~` is defined by user's context.

It is possible to replace each `~` with $HOME path:

```
 sed -i "s|~|$HOME|g" your-script.sh
```

And/Or include users context in your script:

```
 sed -i "2i source $HOME/.bash_profile" your-script.sh
```